# Summing up the total based on the random number of inputs of a column

Tags: python, calculated-columns, data-processing

I need to sum up the "value" column amount for each value of col1 of the File1 and export it to an output file. I'm new in python and need to do it for thousands of records.

### File1

```
col1 col2              value
559 1   91987224    2400000000
559 0   91987224    100000000
558 0   91987224    100000000
557 2   87978332    500000000
557 1   59966218    2400000000
557 0   64064811    100000000
```

### Desired Output:

```
col1      Sum 
559     2500000000
558     1000000000
557     3000000000
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S : I can't use the pandas library due to permission issues.I tried the following code. Sharing it with trace backs:

```
import csv 
fin = open("File1.txt","r")
list_txid = {}
num_tx = {}
amount_tx = {}

for line in fin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    f = line.split("\t")
    txid = f[0]
    amount = int(f[3])

fin.close()
for txid in list_txid:
    num_tx[txid] += 1
    amount_tx[txid] += amount
    print("{0}\t{1:d}\t{2:d}".format(txid, amount_tx[txid]))
```

### Traceback :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users....\sum.py", line 14, in 
    amount = int(f[3])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far and what's the problem

Comment: attempted code shared with tracebacks, tnx - @Slam

Comment: @MikeScotty ...Please check my question again. I had edited as per the requirement.  Kindly, lift the downvote from the post. tnx in advance .

Comment: Removed my Downvote. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', delim_whitespace=True)

#      col1      col2       value
# 559     1  91987224  2400000000
# 559     0  91987224   100000000
# 558     0  91987224   100000000
# 557     2  87978332   500000000
# 557     1  59966218  2400000000
# 557     0  64064811   100000000

result = df.groupby(df.index)['value'].sum().reset_index()

#    index       value
# 0    557  3000000000
# 1    558   100000000
# 2    559  2500000000

result.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use pandas, unfortunately . I have edited the question with my attempt and would appreciate if you could guide me on this.  @jpp

Answer (score 1):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for create `DataFrame`, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by index by `level=0` and aggregate `sum`. Last export [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file1)
df.groupby(level=0)['value'].sum().to_file(file2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use pandas, unfortunately. I have edited the question with my attempt and would appreciate if you could guide me on this.